# What does it mean that two strings have the same linguistic meaning?

Tags: string, swift, unicode, string-comparison

In the swift documentation for [comparing strings](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH7-ID298), I found the following:

> Two String values (or two Character values) are considered equal if
>   their extended grapheme clusters are canonically equivalent. ***Extended
>   grapheme clusters are canonically equivalent if they have the same
>   linguistic meaning and appearance***, even if they are composed from
>   different Unicode scalars behind the scenes.

Then the documentation proceeds with the following example which shows two strings that are "cannonically equivalent"

> For example, LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE (U+00E9) is canonically
>   equivalent to LATIN SMALL LETTER E (U+0065) followed by COMBINING
>   ACUTE ACCENT (U+0301). Both of these extended grapheme clusters are
>   valid ways to represent the character é, and so they are considered to
>   be canonically equivalent:

Ok. Somehow `e` and `é` look the same and also have the same linguistic meaning. Sure I'll give them that. I have taken a Spanish class sometime and the prof wasn't too strict on whether we used either forms of `e`, so I'm guessing this is what they are referring to. Fair enough

The documentation goes further to show two strings that are not canonically equivalent:

> Conversely, LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A (U+0041, or "A"), as used in
>   English, is not equivalent to CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER A (U+0410, or
>   "А"), as used in Russian. The characters are visually similar, but do
>   not have the same linguistic meaning:

Now here is where the alarm bells go off and I decide to ask this question. It seems that appearance has nothing to do with it because the two strings look **exactly** the same, and they also admit this in the documentation. So it seems that what the string class is really looking for is `linguistic meaning`?

This is why I ask what it means by the strings having the same/different linguistic meaning, because `e` is the only form of `e` that I know which is mainly used in English, but I have only seen `é` being used in languages like French or Spanish, so why is it that the given that `А` is used in Russian and `A` is used in English, is what causes the string class to say that they are not equivalent?

I hope I was able to walk you through my thought process, now my question is what does it mean for two strings to have the same linguistic meaning (in code if possible)?

Comment: Canonical equivalence is defined in the Unicode Standard [Annex #15](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr15/tr15-43.html) and [Section 3.11](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode8.0.0/ch03.pdf). If two strings have the same canonical representation then they are canonically equivalent.

Comment: @jonrsharpe missed that. Thanks

Comment: What don't you get from the counter-example, with the two different ways to get é?

Comment: Same linguistic meaning in code... "Go away" == "Shoo!"

Comment: @jonrsharpe why are `e` and `é` considered the same, but `A` and `А` are not? It just baffles me how they decided that

Comment: ...because it's é and é? I.e. they're both é, but written in two different ways in Unicode. *"`LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE (U+00E9)` is canonically equivalent to `LATIN SMALL LETTER E (U+0065)` **followed by `COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT (U+0301)`**"*

Comment: @Smac89 In general, that's a matter for linguistic experts, but in the case of the "A"s, the letters are from two different alphabets. Some of the letters in Cyrillic look the same as Latin letters, but others don't.

Comment: @jonrsharpe My problem is that if I were programming something like this and the user types in `A` when I was expecting `А`, then debugging would be hell. But apart from that, I am more interested in how the string class is deriving linguistic meaning.

Comment: @Smac89 I really don't understand what it is that you don't understand, and therefore what you're trying to ask.

Comment: The question has been answered. This is Unicode. Canonical equivalence is technically well-defined under Unicode. End of story. You can perhaps blame Apple's documentation for trying to _explain_ this Unicode concept and not just referring you _to_ the Unicode documentation. But there is nothing to ask about or argue with; it's a matter of plain fact.

Comment: `é` is `é`, `a` is not `а`.

Answer (score 3):

You said:

> Somehow e and é look the same and also have the same linguistic meaning.

No. You have misread the document. Here's the document again:

> LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE (U+00E9) is canonically equivalent to LATIN SMALL LETTER E (U+0065) followed by COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT (U+0301).

Here's U+00E9: é
Here's U+0065: e
Here's U+0301:  ´
Here's U+0065 followed by U+0301: é

So U+00E9 (é) looks and means the same as U+0065 U+0301 (é). Therefore they must be treated as equal.

So why is Cyrillic А different from Latin A? [UTN #26](http://www.unicode.org/notes/tn26/) gives several reasons. Here are some:

- “Traditional graphology has always treated them as distinct scripts, …”
- “Literate users of Latin, Greek, and Cyrillic alphabets do not have cultural conventions of treating each other's alphabets and letters as part of their own writing systems.”
- “Even more significantly, from the point of view of the problem of character encoding for digital textual representation in information technology, the preexisting identification of Latin, Greek, and Cyrillic as distinct scripts was carried over into character encoding, from the very earliest instances of such encodings.”
- “[A] unified encoding of Latin, Greek, and Cyrillic would make casing operations an unholy mess, …”

Read the tech note for full details.